# File Uploading in asp.net MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an app in asp.net mvc in which I want to upload a file and in view I used rendercontrol for rendering the file uploader. In view I am using the following code

```
<%: Html.RenderControl(new ControlInfo ()
                                                                {
                                                                    ControlID = item.ProjAttID,
                                                                    DefaultValue = item.DefaultValue,
                                                                    CanNull = item.CanNull, 
                                                                    // This field can be null. So, if field is null then don't pick the value of expression
                                                                    // from Regular Expression table. 
                                                                    RegularExpression = (item.RegularExpression != null)?  item.RegularExpression1.Value: null,
                                                                    ErrorMessage = (item.RegularExpression != null) ? item.RegularExpression1.Error : "",
                                                                    Type = (ControlType)item.FieldType,
                                                                    Value = (TempData["__" + item.ProjAttID] != null)? TempData["__" + item.ProjAttID].ToString() : null,
                                                                    ControlAttName = item.ProjAttName,
                                                                    RegExpressionID = (item.RegularExpression != null) ? item.RegularExpression1.ExpressionID : -1
                                                                }, true
                                                             )
                                    %>
```

and in my controller I am using the following code to save the file

```
int i = new Random().Next();
            string fileName = i + Path.GetFileName(data[3]);

            fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "-");

            string trailingPath = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/"), trailingPath);
            ____.SaveAs(fullPath);
```

I am getting the file name but now I am unable to understand how I can save this file. What code I can write "**_*.SaveAs(fullPath)" in this space "*_**" so I can save my file. Please help me

Regards

My controlrenderhelper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using UserInterface.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;

namespace UserInterface.HtmlHelpers
{
    // This enum defines the control types.
    public enum ControlType
    {
        TextField = 1,
        Password = 2,
        TextArea = 3,
        List = 4,
        CheckBox = 5,
        //06-03-2012
        UploadField = 6
        //
    }

    public static class ControlRenderHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RenderControl(this HtmlHelper html, ControlInfo pControlInfo, bool pSaveInfo, int pListSetID = 1)
        {
            string scriptString = "";
            MvcHtmlString controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create("");
            Dictionary<string, string> attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            TagBuilder tag;

            if (pControlInfo.RegExpressionID == 6)
            {
                // Adding jquery code to show datepicker widget
                scriptString = "<script>$(function() { $('#_" + pControlInfo.ControlID + "').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yy' });});</script>";
            }

            switch (pControlInfo.Type)
            {
                case ControlType.TextField:

                    tag = new TagBuilder("input");

                    // Tag attributes.
                    attributes.Add("type", "text");
                    attributes.Add("id", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("name", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);

                    // For client side validation (using Jquery).
                    if (!pControlInfo.CanNull)
                    {
                        attributes.Add("class", "required");
                    }

                    if (pControlInfo.Value != null)
                    {
                        attributes.Add("value", pControlInfo.Value);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        attributes.Add("value", pControlInfo.DefaultValue);
                    }

                    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);

                    // For client side validation.
                    scriptString += GetValidationScript(pControlInfo.ControlID, pControlInfo.RegularExpression, pControlInfo.ErrorMessage);
                    controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString() + scriptString);

                    break;

                case ControlType.CheckBox:

                    tag = new TagBuilder("input");

                    // Tag attributes.
                    attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");
                    attributes.Add("id", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("name", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("value", "Yes");
                    if (pControlInfo.Value == "Yes")
                    {
                        attributes.Add("checked", "yes");
                    }

                    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);
                    tag.InnerHtml = "  " + pControlInfo.ControlAttName;
                    controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());

                    break;

                case ControlType.TextArea:

                    tag = new TagBuilder("textarea");

                    // Tag attributes.
                    attributes.Add("rows", "4");
                    attributes.Add("cols", "40");
                    attributes.Add("id", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("name", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);

                    // For client side validation (using Jquery).
                    if (!pControlInfo.CanNull)
                    {
                        attributes.Add("class", "required");
                    }

                    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);

                    if (pControlInfo.Value != null)
                    {
                        tag.InnerHtml = pControlInfo.Value;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        tag.InnerHtml = pControlInfo.DefaultValue;
                    }

                    scriptString += GetValidationScript(pControlInfo.ControlID, pControlInfo.RegularExpression, pControlInfo.ErrorMessage);
                    controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString() + scriptString);

                    break;

                case ControlType.List:

                    tag = new TagBuilder("select");
                    string[] options = pControlInfo.DefaultValue.Split(';');
                    string selectedValue = pControlInfo.Value;
                    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

                    // Tag attributes.
                    attributes.Add("id", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("name", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("class", "selectSize");
                    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);

                    foreach (string val in options)
                    {
                        TagBuilder optionTag = new TagBuilder("option");
                        optionTag.InnerHtml = val;

                        if (val == selectedValue)
                        {
                            optionTag.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
                        }

                        temp.Append(optionTag.ToString());
                    }

                    tag.InnerHtml = temp.ToString();
                    controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());

                    break;

                case ControlType.Password:

                    tag = new TagBuilder("input");

                    // Tag attributes.
                    attributes.Add("type", "password");
                    attributes.Add("id", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("name", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);

                    // For client side validation (using Jquery).
                    if (!pControlInfo.CanNull)
                    {
                        attributes.Add("class", "required");
                    }

                    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);

                    // For client side validation.
                    scriptString = GetValidationScript(pControlInfo.ControlID, pControlInfo.RegularExpression, pControlInfo.ErrorMessage);
                    controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString() + scriptString);

                    break;

                case ControlType.UploadField:

                    tag = new TagBuilder("input");

                    // Tag attributes.
                    attributes.Add("type", "file");
                    attributes.Add("id", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    attributes.Add("name", "_" + pControlInfo.ControlID);

                    // For client side validation (using Jquery).
                    if (!pControlInfo.CanNull)
                    {
                        attributes.Add("class", "required");
                    }

                    if (pControlInfo.Value != null)
                    {
                        attributes.Add("value", pControlInfo.Value);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        attributes.Add("value", pControlInfo.DefaultValue);
                    }

                    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);

                    // For client side validation.
                    scriptString += GetValidationScript(pControlInfo.ControlID, pControlInfo.RegularExpression, pControlInfo.ErrorMessage);
                    controlString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString() + scriptString);

                    break;
            }

            if (pSaveInfo)
            {
                if (pListSetID == 1)
                {
                    // Please see the RenderedControlsInfo class to understand the purpose of following code snippet.
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L1ControlsID.Add(pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L1ControlsRegExpression.Add(pControlInfo.RegularExpression);
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L1ControlsCanNullProperty.Add(pControlInfo.CanNull);
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L1ControlsErrorMessage.Add(pControlInfo.ErrorMessage);
                }

                else
                {
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L2ControlsID.Add(pControlInfo.ControlID);
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L2ControlsRegExpression.Add(pControlInfo.RegularExpression);
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L2ControlsCanNullProperty.Add(pControlInfo.CanNull);
                    RenderedControlsInfo.L2ControlsErrorMessage.Add(pControlInfo.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            return controlString;
        }

        static string GetValidationScript(long pControlID, string pRegExp, string pErrorMessage)
        {
            string validationScript = null;

            if (pRegExp != null)
            {
                pRegExp = pRegExp.Replace("/", @"\/");
                // For client side validation.
                validationScript = "<script> $(function() {$.validator.addMethod('_" + pControlID + "', function(value, element) {" +
                                        "return this.optional(element) || /" + pRegExp + "/i.test(value); }, '" + pErrorMessage + "');$('#_" +
                                         pControlID + "').rules('add', '_" + pControlID + "');});</script>";

            }

            return validationScript;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's this `Html.RenderControl` coming from? AFAIK there's no such helper in standard ASP.NET MVC. Also what's `ControlInfo`? Finally which file upload control you are using?

Comment: I am using my own coded Control Render Helper class

Comment: OK, and you expect us answering your question? You wrote custom code which you do not show nor explain what it does nor tell anything about it, and ask us how to use? Are you serious?

Comment: Dear user, If you are going to Vote Down then please tell me the solution then you can do Vote Down.

Comment: No, Snake, no . You will need to provide far more details before this question starts to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a basis, it works for me:

[View]

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   { %>
   <input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="upload" />
<% } %>
```

[Actions]

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/" + file.FileName));
    }
    return View();
}
```

The important thing for the view is that the form needs to have the enctype set to multipart/form-data. In the action the parameter needs to have the same name as in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `HttpPostedFileBase` to your action.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a parameter to a C# method?

Comment: Yes, because I tried to use HttpPostedFileBase but I failed to do so

Comment: var postedFile = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
 I tried to do some thing like that but failed

Comment: Add an `HttpPostedFileBase` _parameter_ to the action method.  (You could also just use `Request.Files[0].SaveAs`)

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Exception is coming :(

Comment: Then you don't actually have a file.

Comment: I have a file and I am getting the file name from string[] data = base.CollectData(pFormData); in data[2] file name is available